# Button pressed state padding occuring on normal state

Tags: android, shapes, android-button

I have a 3d looking button at normal state with 3dp paddings on the right and bottom, when I press the button I want it to look 3d with 3dp paddings on left and top this time. But when I change the padding values of the pressed state of my item shape, the changes in padding shows even when the button is at normal state/not pressed.

My button looks like this:

[image]

And I want it too look like this when pressed:

[image]

**btn_gray1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#acacac" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#acacac" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#c2c2c2"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#c2c2c2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**btn_gray2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#acacac" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#acacac" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="3dp"
                android:bottom="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#959595"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#959595" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="3dp"
                android:bottom="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**btn_gray.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_gray2"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_gray1"/>  
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it this way

your button in xml layout

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TUTORIAL"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

Create a selector xml inside drawable folder
button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_one"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_backgroun_two" />

</selector>
```

button_background_one.xml inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#959595" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#959595" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="3dp"
                android:top="3dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#c2c2c2"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#c2c2c2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="3dp"
                android:top="3dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

button_backgroun_two.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#959595" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#959595" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="3dp"
                android:bottom="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#c2c2c2"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#c2c2c2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="3dp"
                android:bottom="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This should work.Try it

Comment: This is nicely working and also looks easier to manage than my code! Thanks!